# Android update application

Tags: android

I want to ask a little issue which I found out why testing my application. When I update my application from Android Market after I upload new apk, everything is working fine without any errors. But when I try to install older apk manually, not from market and after that install newer version of it again not from market, there are some errors which I don't get if I update my app from market.

Any ideas if it's normal, because as I know Android market app takes care of installing the updates and etc.

Comment: Errors actually are not really important because if I download my app from market and update it there are no problems. But if I install the app and update it manually by trying to install the new apk there are some conflicts with the design and some functionallity. I just forget to mention that in both cases my app is signed and it's release mode.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am having same issue. Updates not working for my new app. It shows update in Play Store. But when users click on update, it says that "the app is already installed. Error code -1"

Answer (score 2):

it's normal if in your phone have a debug version , 
you must unistall old version on your phone, so after you can install the apk ( market version) manually .

for market update , you can update it only if your app is gratis.

Comment: No, I'm using release versions in both cases.